# Some sort of `map` of columns, avoiding re-computation of a parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

First, I'm a newcomer to Oracle, so my question may be stupid.
I will however try to be clear.

I have several tables I'd like to update. Each with the same structure: a first special column, then `n` columns, and finally `n` columns, which will somehow mirror the `n` previous.  (Hence, the table will have 2×n+1 columns). Note that the value of n will vary from one table to another.

For example, for a table `TABLE_A`, I have the following named columns:

```
COL_A_0, COL_A_1, COL_A_2, ..., COL_A_n, COL_A_1_bis, COL_A_2_bis, ..., COL_A_n_bis
```

Now, what I would like to do is something like that. I have two (deterministic) functions `f` and `g`. I want to do the following:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A SET
    COL_1_bis = f(g(COL_A_0), COL_A_1),
    COL_2_bis = f(g(COL_A_0), COL_A_2),
    ...,
    COL_n_bis = f(g(COL_A_0), COL_A_n);
```

Now, the point is computing `g(COL_A_0)` is quite slow, and I would like to avoid recomputing it for each column I have to update (every `bis` column). Beware that the value of `g(COL_A_0)` will change from row to row.
Furthermore, I will want to apply the previous scheme to several tables, not all with the same number of columns. For example, `TABLE_A` will have 2×3+1 columns, while `TABLE_B` will have 2×5+1.

The first idea I had was to generate the command in a string, by first computing only once the value of `g(COL_A_0)`, and then `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` the computed string. But it does not work as the value of `g(COL_A_0)` changes for each row.

The perfect thing would be be be able to write something like:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A SET
    (COL_1_bis, ..., COL_n_bis) = map(f, g(COL_A_0), (COL_A_1, ..., COL_A_n));
```

I can't imagine that something that simple does not have an elegant and efficient solution. It seems to me it is quite a common pattern.

Comment: You may want to read about scalar subquery caching. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51asktom-453438.html) is a post on this subject by Tom Kyte.

Answer (score 0):

Is this possible for you? Assuming you are doing this using procedure. If you want to update many rows, best would be iterate using the cursor. But, cursor is processing row by row and it will be time consuming.

```
declare g_col_a datatype;
begin
select g(cola_0) into g_col_a from table where .......
update table
end;
/
```